# Could you please add two synonyms to the 'quality' tag?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Please, make the [quality-assurance](https://askubuntu.com/tags/quality-assurance) and [qa](https://askubuntu.com/tags/qa) tags synonyms of the [quality](https://askubuntu.com/tags/quality) tag, as I do not have enough reputation to do that.

*quality* should be the "master" tag because it is the one that was initially announced by Nicholas Skaggs on his [email to the Ubuntu-quality mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-quality/2012-December/002970.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed.

Comment: Great, thank you!